# How to communicate from a background to a sidebar script in Firefox WebExtensions? (or vice versa)

Tags: javascript, opera, firefox-addon-webextensions

I am migrating my extension from the SDK to WebExtensions, and I can not find the way of communicating between a background script and the sidebar. The idea is to pass the text the user highlights and some extra info when he clicks in a context menu. I need to copy this selection in the "selected-text" input, but I can not manipulate the DOM of the sidebar from the script...: (

```js
browser.contextMenus.create({
  id: "save-highlighted-data",
  title: browser.i18n.getMessage("save-data"),
  contexts: ["all"],
  onclick: function(info,tab){ 

    //I got the highlighted data
    console.log("Selected text: " + info.selectionText);

    browser.sidebarAction.setPanel({ 
      panel: browser.extension.getURL("/sidebar/annotation.html")   
    }).then(function(){ 

      //In this context, "this" = the chrome window. But I can not change the document
      //  of the sidebar
      //console.log("window", this.document.querySelector("#selected-text"));
    }); 
  },
  command: "_execute_sidebar_action" //This toggles the sidebar 
});
```

Any idea? I checked the sidebar examples at the GitHub repo, but they just open a sidebar with not more communication that the sidebar toggle action (`"_execute_sidebar_action"`)

Comment: Have you tried `runtime.sendMessage()` and `runtime.onMessage.addListener()`? 
You can also get access to the DOM from sidebar but that involves using `tabs.query()` to find the active tab since sidebars are not attached to a particular tab.

Comment: @erosman thanks, that's the answer. It worked with runtime. Would you liketo post it as an answer? PS: one last question > how can you use tabs.query() if the sidebar has no tab? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extension's background, content, sidebar, etc scripts can communicate with each other using [runtime.sendMessage()](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/sendMessage) and [runtime.onMessage.addListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onMessage)

AFAIK, there isn't any direct connection between sidebar and content DOM at the moment.

You can use [tabs.query()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query) to get the **Active Tab** (which is the visible tab) or any other tab

```
function logTabs(tabs) {
  for (let tab of tabs) {
    // tab.url requires the `tabs` permission
    console.log(tab.url);
  }
}

function onError(error) {
  console.log(`Error: ${error}`);
}

var querying = browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true});
querying.then(logTabs, onError);
```

Or

```
chrome.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true}, function (tabs) {
  // tabs[0] is the active tab
});
```

You can then use [tabs.executeScript()](https://developer.mozilla.org/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/executeScript) with the **tabId** you got from `tabs.query()` (i.e. `tabs[0].id`) to inject JavaScript code into the page (DOM) and interact with its DOM.

Comment: Thanks you so much!